# Prevent printing url while window.print

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using javascript `window.print();` to print web-page. On printout, it is showing url like `http:\...`

How i could avoid it?

Comment: complete html print using `window.print();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't control this in javascript, it has to be done at the browser level.

This post explains how to do it in Firefox and IE
http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/the-geek-blog/prevent-firefox-or-internet-explorer-from-printing-the-url-on-every-page/

What we have done in the past is just have a link explaining to the user how to do this for their browser.

**EDIT**

What we've also done is generate a PDF so that you can make the page look the same across all browsers. [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.com/) is a free tool to do this. Just a note, it is kinda unfriendly. There is an example [here](http://imak47.wordpress.com/2008/09/19/generating-pdf-document-in-net-using-itextsharp-library/). Basically, you input HTML and it converts it to a PDF.

Comment: What can be done at programming level? Please answer if it can be in C#.net

Comment: @MayP As far as forcing the browser to not show the URL goes, there is nothing you can do, it's all client side. I appended to my answer a method we've used when we need to customize a print page.

Answer (score 0):

Add a title. It overrides the url

```
<head>
    <title>My title</title>
</head>
```